# Naming a condition if-value for use in if block

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin

To limit the amount of double code instances i would like to name my variables in if statement much like you do in for loops.

My expression:

```
var hours = if (this.substringBefore(":").toInt() != 0) 
   {this.substringBefore(":") + "h" }
   {else ""}
```

I want something like:

```
var hours = if (MY_VAR = this.substringBefore(":").toInt() != 0) 
   { MY_VAR + "h" }
   else { "" }
```

I mainly write in kotlin, but I'm interested in finding other languages that does this.

Comment: Almost every Turing Language - lol. C, C++, Java, C# etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kotlin, I'd recommend to use higher-order functions for creating such a temporary variable, like `let`:

```
this.substringBefore(":").let { myval ->
     if (myval.toInt() != 0) {
         myval + "h"
     } else ""
}
```